# How to concatenate specific String from Array ? [SwiftUI]

Tags: arrays, concatenation, swiftui

I have an array :

```
struct Main: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var value: String
    var type: String
}
var mainArray = [Main]()
```

And I need to output the "var value" of each of the elements which are in this array into a Text("")

Like : `Text("(main[index].value)")`

But I don't know the correct way of doing that

Also, I wiil need to be able to tweak the value I get with a function like :

```
func readMain() -> String {
        if main[index].value == "specificContent" { return "Correct" }
        else { return "Incorrect"}
    }
```

And then add my `Text(readMain())` but that return all the values from the array like : 
`Text("Correct, Incorrect, Incorrect, Correct, Correct")`

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
@State private var mainArray = [Main]()

var body: some View {
    ForEach(mainArray) { main in
        Text(
            main.value == "correctValue" ?
            "Correct" :
            "Incorrect"
        )
    }
}
```

This prints whether the value property (of each Main element in you mainArray) is "correct" seperately.

If you want, though, your text to appear in one line with a space character separating the different mainArray values you could do this:

```
@State private var mainArray = [Main]()

var body: some View {
    Text(
        mainArray
            .map {
                $0.value == "correctValue" ?
                    "Correct" :
                    "Incorrect"
            }
            .joined(separator: " ")
    )
}
```

In the above sample the mainArray is converted into an string array containing a description of whether the values are "correct" and then these values are joined into one string with the space character (" ") separating them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think it getting close to the solution :)
The "Correct" "Incorrect" thing was just an exemple, in fact the values in my Array could be : "book title 1", "movie title 2", "book title 2", etc...

And I want to output : Text("book title 1, movie title 2, book title 2")

I tried with your first exemple code by just writing "Text( main.value )" and it output all of the values which is cool, but I need to be able to separate the different values (using a point, or a comma, as I wish) 

Is it possible ?
Thanks again !